# Why is the "max norm" for matrices not an operator norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

While the operator norms on matrices commonly used in science and engineering (especially, the 2-norm or the spectral norm), there are also other norms cited in the literature, such as the Frobenius norm.

For an $ m \times n$ matrix $A$, the Frobenius norm is defined by
$$
\Vert A \Vert_F = \sqrt{\mbox{Trace}(A^T A)}  = \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^m
\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \ | a_{ij} |^2   }
$$
and the max norm is defined by
$$
\Vert A \Vert_\max = \max\limits_{i, j} \ | a_{ij} |
$$

The operator norm is defined as follows:

$$
\Vert A \Vert = \max\limits_{x \neq 0, \ \ x \in \mathbf{R}^n} \
{ \Vert A x \Vert_m \over \Vert x \Vert_n }
$$
where $\Vert \cdot \Vert_m$, $\Vert \cdot \Vert_n$ are vector
norms on $\mathbf{R}^m$ and $\mathbf{R}^n$ respectively.

It is easy to show that the Frobenius norm is not an operator norm.

Indeed,
$$
\Vert I \Vert_F = \sqrt{n}
$$
while
$$
\Vert I \Vert = 1
$$
for any operator norm.

This argument does not work to show that "max-norm" is not an operator norm
as we know that
$$
\Vert I \Vert_\max = \max\limits_{i,j} | \delta_{ij} | = 1
$$

How to show that the max-norm is not an operator norm?

Your help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you experimented with a few 2-by-2 matrix calculations?

Comment: A nice example is that rotation matrices are isometries, so have operator norm $1$ - but there are rotation matrices with all entries having modulus less than $1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subordinate matrix norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67278/subordinate-matrix-norm). – Also: [Norm $\|A\|$ is not induced by any vector norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/97966/42969)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike suggested, I worked with some examples.

I took
$$
A = \left[ \matrix{1 & 2 \cr
        3 & 4 \cr} \right], \ \
  B = \left[ \matrix{4 & 3 \cr
2 & 1 \cr} \right]
$$

Then
$$
A B = \left[ \matrix{ 8 & 5 \cr 20 & 13 \cr} \right]
$$

We find that
$$
\Vert A B \Vert_\max = 20
$$
while
$$
\Vert A \Vert_\max \Vert B \Vert_\max = 4 \times 4 = 16
$$

Hence, for the chosen $2 \times 2$ matrices $A$ and $B$,
$$
\Vert A B \Vert_\max > \Vert A \Vert_\max \Vert B \Vert_\max
$$

This violates the property for operator norms given by
$$
\Vert A B \Vert \leq \Vert A \Vert \Vert B \Vert
$$

Hence, we conclude that the "max norm" is not an operator norm.

(I hope that this argument is OK - thanks!)